# Using Piping with cat and less to concatenate 2 files

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line, unix, pipe

I'm fairly new to Unix commands and I just have a simple question.

One exercise I'm working on wants me to use piping along with cat and less to concatenate 2 directories (in this case /etc/passwd and /etc/group) together and then display the output one page at a time.

I've been trying `ls - la | less cat  /etc/passwd/ - /etc/group` but I'm not sure of the exact syntax I should use. What should I change?

EDIT: Changed directories to files in the title for future reference.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When using pipes, you want to consider the order of operations before fashioning your pipeline. You'll also want to have a good understanding of what each command does.

For clarification: /etc/passwd and /etc/group are not *directories*, but *files*. You're on the right track using `ls` for directories, but in this case it is not needed.

To get you started, here are a few tips (also try `man <command>` for more details).

`less` is great for displaying paginated output.

`cat` is great for printing the contents of a file (or multiple) in a single stream to STDOUT.

Putting those together:

`cat /etc/group /etc/passwd | less` means "concatenate the two specified files (passwd and group) and pipe the resulting output to less, which displays them in paginated form.

Comment: Great explanation and pointing out `man` is a great idea for a unix greenhorn.  Just one thing to add for the OP:  If you are searching for something (specific word or whatever), when in `less`, `man`, or `vim`, you can type `/` and then provide search criteria (`n` goes to the next match, assuming it exists).

Answer (score 5):

First of all, you are talking about *files*, not directories. Also, the `ls` is irrelevant. All you need to do is

```
cat   /etc/passwd/ /etc/group | less
```

`cat`simply prints the contents of the files you give it, giving it two files will cause it to output the contents of one after the other. `less` is a pager, a program that allows you to read multi-line data one page at a time.